# First row as column names in a list of data frames(2)

Tags: r, dataframe, list, r-rownames

I want to rename the columns of every data frame in my list of data frames with the first row.

I tried the code from this question [First row as column names in a list of data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52385264/first-row-as-column-names-in-a-list-of-data-frames)
 but it returns *first_row_name=rows_number* /*c(date=3)*/

```
dflist1 <- lapply(dflist, function(x){
  names(x) <- x[1,]
  x <- x[-1,]
  return(x)
})
```

Comment: Try `names(x) <- as.character(unlist(x[1,]))`

Comment: What does the first row look like? Could you paste some sample data? Are there any weird characters in the first row?

Comment: `x[-1,]` likely comes back as a data frame--subsetting a data frame gets you another data frame. You need to turn it into a vector to supply it to `names`

Comment: @akrun that solved my problem

Comment: @Mar I posted my comment as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the columns were `factor`.  So, we `unlist` and convert to `character` class

```
names(x) <- as.character(unlist(x[1,]))
```